# Explanation for the implicit argument in my Ocaml code

Tags: ocaml

I don't understand the following OCaml code as I am not sure how the **extract_ident** function infers that the unary parameter is **string_lexer** when it does not explicitly specify it and how it's passed into **extract**. I understand that you can have a function without the **match** construct and the type in the pattern matching is the last argument, but I don't understand how **string_lexer** argument is passed into **extract** implicitly?

```
type string_lexer = {string:string; mutable current:int; size:int } ;;

let init_lex s = {string=s, current=0; size=String.length s} ;;
let forward cl = cl.current <- cl.current+1 ;;
let forward_n cl n = cl.current <- cl.current+n ;;
let extract pred cl =
    let st = cl.string and pos = cl.current in
    let rec ext n = if n<cl.size && (pred st.[n]) then ext (n+1) else n in
    let res = ext pos in
    cl.current <- res; String.sub cl.string pos (res-pos) ;;

let extract_int =
    let is_int = function '0'..'9' -> true | _ -> false
    in function cl -> int_of_string (extract is_int cl);;

let extract_ident =
    let is_alpha_num = function
        'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_' -> true
        | _ -> false
    in extract is_alpha_num ;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the answer is *currying* and partial application. When you write

```
let f x y = ...
```

then `f x` is a function of one more argument (`y`).

In your example, OCaml can infer the type of this argument for `extract_ident` because it forwards to `extract` via partial application, and that function does `cl.string` and `cl.current` on its `cl` argument. Record labels uniquely determine the corresponding record type. (If more than one record type with the same label is in scope, then the last one wins, although the latest OCaml version added some extra smartness for cases not relevant to your example.)